# Using @Html.Raw MVC 4 display issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am pulling a string from a database using my model that looks like this: `You <h3>look</h3> funny`

so in my view I do this: @Html.Raw(Model.myfield)

So I am expecting

> You **look** funny

Instead I get:

> You
>   **look**
>   funny

Comment: What do you mean? are you expecting it to be bold? have a break point? describe more about what you get and what you are trying to get.

Comment: MVC or not, `You <h3>look</h3> funny` is never going to display in one line without CSS explicitly telling it to do so.

Comment: Use "You <b>look</b> funny" instead of <h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h3>` is a block element.
It breaks inline flows around it.

You may want `<strong>`, which is inline.

Comment: Sorry those who could understand what I was asking, yes I want everything on 1 line not 3 line, I didn't realize using <h3> tag would put a break before and after the tag, I don't use html that often.